# UIWebView load a local HTML show nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

When I use `UIWebView` to load a local HTML resource by Path, but sometime it will show nothing in the view. I use code like this

```
NSString *path = @"local Path ";
NSString *timeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%f", [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970]];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:timeStamp];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

most time it can work normal. but sometime it work bad.

Comment: Have you set the delegate of webView, if not set and implement its method and check it is not going in failToLoad method.

Comment: yes, i set the delegate and most time it's ok. I think that becase loadRequest method is asynchronous, and the data also. so I change the load file by loadHTMLString, but I can't make sure it's right.

Comment: Define "works bad". We need more informations about that.